# Traversing an ExcelRange with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to read data from an excel file. At one point, I want to get a row of data as an `ExcelRange` and pass it into another function. But when I try to traverse the `ExcelRange` in that function, it seems to reassign the `ExcelRange`.

For instance, if I do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(excelRange.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(excelRange[1, 1].Text);
Console.WriteLine(excelRange.ToString());
```

the output I get is

```
C41:BP41
Training
A1
```

("Training" is the text in cell A1 of my spreadsheet, not in cell C41)

If I instead try to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(excelRange.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(excelRange[excelRange.Start.Row, excelRange.Start.Column].Text);
Console.WriteLine(excelRange.ToString());
```

then I get

```
C41:BP41

C41
```

Is there a way to traverse a `ExcelRange` without it changing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, but am hoping someone knows of a better way. Here's what I've got that works:

```
int startRow = excelRange.Start.Row;
int startCol = excelRange.Start.Column;
int endCol = excelRange.End.Column;
for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++)
{
    string cellText = excelRange[startRow, i].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can get list of values in cells as

```
int startRow = excelRange.Start.Row;
int startCol = excelRange.Start.Column;
int endRow = excelRange.End.Row;
int endCol = excelRange.End.Column;

var rowValues=(object[,]) worksheet.Cells[startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol].Value;
List<string> lstValues = rowValues.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
```